# Show that the largest eigen value of the matrix $A=[a_{ij}]_{n\times n}$ is $< 2n+1$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Show that the largest eigen value of the matrix $A=[a_{ij}]_{n\times n}$ is $< 2n+1$.
>
> $$A=\begin{bmatrix} n-2&0&1&1&1&\ldots &1\\0 &n-2&1&1&1&\ldots &1\\1&1&n-1&1&1&\ldots &1\\1&1&1&n-1&1&\ldots &1\\1&1&1&1&n-1&\ldots &1\\\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots\\\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots\\1&1&1&1&1&\ldots &n-1\end{bmatrix}.$$

**Attempt**:

I computed for $n=3$  for which the  eigen  values are $0,1,3$.

I computed for $n=4$  for which the  eigen  values are $0.76,2,2,5.24$.

I computed for $n=5$  for which the  eigen  values are $1.63,3,3,3,7.37$.

I computed for $n=6$  for which the  eigen  values are $2.54,4,4,4,4,9.46$.

So the eigen values are following a definite pattern and satisfy the given inequality in the question.

But is there any special trick to find the largest eigen value without finding the entire spectrum for a general $n\in \Bbb N$.
I am unable to find it.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like all but two eigenvalues are $n-2$. So this begs you to look at $B=A-(n-2)I$ instead. This matrix is $B=J-K$ where $J$ is the all-one
matrix and $K$ is the matrix with ones in the top left two-by-two block
and zeroes elsewhere. Let the standard basis be $e_1,\ldots,e_n$.
Then $e_1-e_2$ and the $e_3-e_k$ ($4\le k\le n$) are $n-2$ linearly
independent vectors killed by $B$. Therefore the characteristic equation
for $B$ is $x^{n-2}(x^2-ax+b)$ for some $a$, $b$. We can identify these
easily enough: $a=n-2$ and $b=-2(n-2)$, etc.

Comment: Unable to understand some points here.

Comment: *Then $e_1-e_2\ldots $ are $n-2$ linearly... killed by $B$*

Comment: I am unable to understand this and also the fact how to determine char.poly of $B$ from here

Comment: Will you please help me out?

Comment: @RishabhPant The matrix $B$ is symmetric, so is diagonalisable. Its kernel has dimension at least $n-2$, so $x^{n-2}$ is a factor of its characteristic polynomial. $a$ is just the trace of $B$ while $b$ is the sum of its "principal" 2-by-2 minors (those symmetric about the diagonal).

Comment: Thank you But Why are we choosing the minors symmetric about the diagonal?

Comment: And how do we get the sum to be $-2(n-2)$.Kindly help